# forcing guzzle to download the zip files

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle

Need help downloading the the json response zip files.
I am using guzzle json response from the remote server which returns filenames and modification dates to me. i want to download all these zip files to my storage folder of local server..

so it would work like this
remote server gives json response filenames
i take the filenames and create my link and force guzzle to download those files to my local server.

Here is my code

```
 ini_set('max_execution_time', '0');

    $url = "https://feeds.example.com/zips/publisher/";
    try
    {

      $client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();

        $res = $client->request('GET', $url, [
            'auth' => ['username', 'password'],

            'headers' => [
                'Accept'     => 'application/json',
                'Content-Type'     => 'application/json'
            ],



        ]);

       $responses = json_decode($res->getBody()->getContents());

       foreach ($responses->incrementalFeed as $feed)
       {
            $downloadLink = $url . $feed->name;
            $client->get($downloadLink, ['auth' => ['username', 'password']]);
            Storage::put($feed->name, $downloadLink);
       }

  }
  catch (ClientException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
  }
```

it downloads all the zip files to my storage folder but all the file are like 1kb , empty .. however in remote website those files are like from 10mb to 600mbs

what am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You’re not downloading anything. 
You need to use guzzle again to download the files

e.g

```
$response = $client->get($downloadLink);
Storage::put($feed->name, $response->getBody());
```